Understanding the caching in ElasticSearch for frequently used filters
I want to get the maximum benefit of cache by caching the response of most frequent filters in the query. To get the maximum benefit of my frequent filters, I am planning this flow:

Whenever user logins, I will first hit the below query (where in my case all the subsequent queries will have atleast the same or more filters).

POST /sample-index/_search
{
   "size": 0, 
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "product_id": ["test-id-1"]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "year": 2022
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



My thinking is whenever there is a next query, where suppose I have more filters(lets say category_id + (product_id + year)), the response will be mush faster, given that I have already cached the results for the filters with (product_id + year)

Is my thinking correct? Is this how the caching works? What I have looked so for is for the given above query, I dont see ES caches it anywhere(fielddata, shard, query). I don't know if it internally caches within OS.
To add on this, even if I clear the cache with _cache/clear api, and then I run the same above query again, I still get the response very quickly sometimes. How's that possible given I have cleared all the cache?
